# Get-PNPFile can't see files created by users when logged in with app/thumb

Tags: pnp-powershell

If I connect to sharepoint via interactive login and add a file I can see it on the sharepoint web site.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Surl -Interactive
Add-PnPFile -Path c:\temp\check1.log -Folder "documents"
```

If I connect with an application and thumbprint and add a file, the file is invisible in the web

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Surl -ClientId $cid -Thumbprint $thumb -Tenant $tenant
Add-PnPFile -Path c:\temp\check2.log -Folder "documents"
```

using `Find-PnPFile -match *.log`
If I am connected with the app/thumb it will only return check2.log.
If I am connected with my user using interactive login it will only return check1.log

The app has "Full control" rights to the sharepoint site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have check in/out enabled?

Since user and app can only see their own (uploaded) documents i.e. user can see check1.log and app can see check2.log - this tell me that the files haven't been checked in after upload. What you can do to check is:

1. On the browser navigate to the "Documents" library and check in the
   document
2. For the document uploaded by the app - navigate to "Library
   Settings" -> "Manage files which have no checked in version" -> take
   ownership and check-in the document

If this works then you need to use the proper parameters to check-in/publish the file with Add-PnPFile. See - https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPFile.html

Comment: #2 That was indeed the issue. After I took ownership all the files appeared on the web. Now to make sure this does not happen again >.<

Comment: Well I thought this was the answer. But upon revisiting it is still not correct. Taking ownership of the files fixed it for the user account. But now the app cannot see any file. I have completely disabled the check-out feature.

Comment: More discoveries. 
This issue was only affecting older files from before checkout was disabled, any new files are unaffected. Uploaded by user or app, they appear working now

Comment: You need to make sure that you check in the document after upload. Unless the system has at least 1 committed version of the document users will not be able to see each others document this includes the app